# Spyder - Shortcut to go to previous file I was editing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, spyder

Is there a navigation shortcut to go to the file I was previously editing?

Case:

say I am switching between `a.py` and `z.py`, and there are a number of other files in between.

I can do `ctrl+pagedown` and scroll all the way, but is there a way to switch quickly between the two files?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You can go to the previous file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. That will you show the following menu of your files, which is organized by most recently visited:

[image: Most recently used files menu]